# how to sort listview item Population wise in android

Tags: java, android

This is my **Activity** Class

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity   {

    // Declare Variables
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Generate sample data
        rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

        country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
                "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
                "Russia", "Japan" };

        population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
                "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
                "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000" };

        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) 
        {
            WorldPopulation wp = new WorldPopulation(rank[i], country[i],
                    population[i]);
            // Binds all strings into an array
            arraylist.add(wp);
        }

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

This is my **Datamodel** Class:

```
public class WorldPopulation {
    private String rank;
    private String country;
    private String population;

    public WorldPopulation(String rank, String country, String population) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.country = country;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public String getPopulation() {
        return this.population;
    }
}
```

I am Printing data in Listview with rank ,Country and Population but I am unable to Sort according to Population wise Currently it display rank wise while I have to print data Population wise in ascending Order means Small Population will Come first then large Population and respectively please help.

Comment: Have you seen comparator

Comment: i have tried Collection.sort and Put arraylist But its not working

Comment: can you post your code which one you tried to sort the arraylist ???

Comment: Collections.sort(list);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make a Comparator that can compare your objects, or if they are all instances of the same class, you can make that class implement Comparable. You can then use Collections.sort() to do the actual sorting.

Please check the below code, theses are not adjact on your need but you can take refrence. why not you keept your data in arraylist instead of array.

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

//Add elements to Arraylist
arrayList.add("1");
arrayList.add("3");
arrayList.add("5");
arrayList.add("2");
arrayList.add("4");


Collections.sort(arrayList);

//display elements of ArrayList
System.out.println("ArrayList elements after sorting in ascending order : ");
for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
```

Collection.sort method will sort in ascending order
or create custorm operator class

```
import java.util.Comparator;

class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
    return strA.compareToIgnoreCase(strB);
  }
}
```

Then on your sort:

```
IgnoreCaseComparator icc = new IgnoreCaseComparator();

java.util.Collections.sort(arrayList,icc);
```

Comment: @MhanazSyed please use arraylist to sort from Collection.sort() please check above update in my answer

Comment: please give the complete code snap of variable declaration or update ur question with new edited code

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/kZgbF2mdfaMgCwFdaxRi5X                      http://paste.ofcode.org/

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are not adding data to your arraylist variable via .add(), look sort() works on collection data only, if I am right please read Arraylist tutorial. Collection is made to do the type of work you are looking for.

Comment: yaar My data Is Printing in Listview how can u say that item is not adding in arraylist

Comment: no wait you data is printing but that population value is in array not in arraylist all is going well, but I think it should be in arraylist to be get sorted. please store it simply in arraylist and apply sort print it.

Comment: Instead of solving few people are marking negative to your points, what type of people they are

Comment: I dont know they dont find Solution so gving me negative

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have declared population as string.
Try long data type.

Comment: That i will Parse but when i use Collection.Sort and Puted arraylist its not sorting

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code to sort any ArrayList

```
 Collections.sort(empList, new Comparator<WorldPopulation>(){
 public int compare(WorldPopulation wp1, WorldPopulation wp2) {
 return emp1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getFirstName());
}
});
```

than notify your adapter that data set changed 
notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: But still its not Soring

Comment: u want to short on some button click

Comment: NO i just want when Application Launch look Populpation i want Sort that  min to max in asceding Order

Comment: than no  need to shot the list short the String array (population) and set it on adapter ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of comparator. You will call it in your main class before setting the adatpter and after calling adaptors constructor. In your case since population is a String so in your comparator you have to convert it in int to apply sorting. You have to something for Comma. Modify blow code according to your requirements.

```
 adapter.sort(new Comparator< WorldPopulation >() {
        @Override
        public int compare(WorldPopulation lhs, WorldPopulation rhs) {
            return Integer.parseInt(lhr.getgetPopulation())-Integer.parseInt(rhs.getPopulation());   //or whatever your sorting algorithm
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still its not working Error in Sort Method no sort method with adapter

Comment: Post your adapter class

Comment: Sort method is available with all the adaptors , you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Well you are doing something wrong , I have used sort with adaptors many times.

Comment: its not showing sort method when adpter. no sor method found